# LMongo package no longer auto loading with Laravel 4 Composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

After my `php composer.phar update` this morning LMongo is no longer added to my autoload files.

From my composer.json file I'm using:

```
"navruzm/lmongo": "*",
"navruzm/laravel-mongo-session": "*",
```

I've removed the modules and composer removed them. I've added it back and it installed again.
It just won't get added to the autoload files anymore. 
I've done a `php composer.phar dump-autoload` numerous times.

Anyone got some ideas to where I should start looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by clearing `/app/storage` after the composer update.

Comment: How do you mean "clearing"? I'm having problems with https://packagist.org/packages/koraktor/steam-condenser - I can manually require the file needed which works, but it doesn't auto load it.  chmod -R 777 storage/ didn't work either :(

Comment: I just removed all the data from the folders in there